# TextView.setText not updating

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following functions:

```kotlin
 fun showVraag(i: Int) {
        var vraag = vragen_en_antwoorden.get(i).first;
        
        println("TEST " + vraag.text);

        val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVraagTitel) as TextView;
        textView.setText(vraag.text);
    }

    fun showVraagNext(view: View) {
        showVraag(++current_vraag);
    }
    fun showVraagPrev(view: View) {
        showVraag(--current_vraag);
    }
```

`showVraag` gets an parameter `i` and simply retrieves a string from a list. It then puts that string into a textview.

`showVraagNext` is the function I call using `onClick` when the next-button is clicked. Same for `showVraagPrev`.

I call `showVraag(0)` in my `onCreate` function and the first element of the array is successfully shown in the TextView. So the function works.

However, when I click on the next-button the `println` successfully shows the next element of the array in my console. But it is not updated in my TextView.

So, my TextView is not updating.
I already tried `textView.invalidate()` or `runOnUIThread` but none of those suggestions worked.
Why is my TextView not updating when I set new text in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your showVraag method does not have access to view. So you need to pass the view also. See the code below where I have reformatted to be more Kotlin style.
Make sure to pass the parent view (not the Button view which you click but the view that holds TextView) to the methods: showVraagNext(view: View) and showVraagPrev(view: View)

```
fun showVraag(i: Int, v: View) {
    var vraag = vragen_en_antwoorden[i].first
    println("TEST " + vraag.text)
    val textView = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtVraagTitel)
    textView.text = vraag.text
}

fun showVraagNext(view: View) {
    showVraag(++current_vraag, view)
}

fun showVraagPrev(view: View) {
    showVraag(--current_vraag, view)
}
```